# How to filter a data frame according to named logical vector

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a named logical, and I want to use it to filter the original data frame where the logical vector is FALSE

I have tried using the conjunction of the two but this doesn't work.

The named logical vector is as below:

```
     fr_Ar_COO             fr_C_S              fr_SH        fr_aldehyde 
          TRUE               TRUE               TRUE              FALSE
```

And I want to filter a data frame which is like this: (the column names)

```
fr_Ar_COO             fr_C_S              fr_SH        fr_aldehyde         active
```

so     `fr_aldehyde` should be filtered out because the logical vector has it equal to FALSE

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
# assuming your data frame is called df,
# and assuming 'v' is the logical vector
df[, names(v)[v]]
```

Using `names(v)[v]` will return only the column names for which the logical vector has a `TRUE` value.

Here is a sample script:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1:3), B=c(4:6), C=c(7:9))
df
v <- c(A=TRUE, B=FALSE, C=TRUE)
df[, names(v)[v]]

  A B C
1 1 4 7
2 2 5 8
3 3 6 9

  A C
1 1 7
2 2 8
3 3 9
```

Comment: What does `v` mean in this solution?

Comment: @NelsonGon Seeing is believing.  Check the example I gave.

Comment: @RonakShah Actually, you're assuming that the order of the named logical vector coincides exactly with the names of the data frame, which may not be the case, [see here](https://rextester.com/CFICK91761).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, you are right! My bad. Thanks :)